# Is the Intersection of these Two Sets a Smooth Manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, lagrange-multiplier

> $A=M\cap N$, $$M=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3| x^2+y^2=1\},$$ $$N=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3|x^2-xy+y^2-z=1\}.$$
>
> **1.** Is $A$ is smooth manifold?
>
> **2.** Find the points of $A$ that are farthest from the origin.

This is what I thought about doing. If I plug in $x^2+y^2=1$ into $x^2-xy+y^2-z=1$, I get $xy=-z$. Which means that the manifold is a hyperbolic paraboloid.

To show that $A$ is manifold, I should find coordinate charts on it and show that they are continuous, and the differential of them is of rank $3$.

Can someone help me to proceed from this step further? Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You might have a hard time showing that the differential has rank $3$, because, if you are to prove that this is a manifold, your best guess on its dimension would be $1$. Euristically: "$\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension $3$, I'm introducing $2$ equations, hence the dimension is $3-2=1$".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How can I show then that it is a manifold? is there any other way?

Comment: You have an algebra error: substituting the first equation into the second gives $xy=-z$. And this is not a cylinder, it is a hyperbolic paraboloid. It also doesn't describe the shape: the shape is described by *both* equations $x^2+y^2=1,xy=-z$.

Comment: I fixed them. Thanks a lot @Ian

Comment: You can parametrize the surface by $z$ now: writing $(x+y)^2=1+2xy=1-2z$, now $x+y = \pm \sqrt{1-2z}$ and $xy=-z$. Now this is an easy system to work with (when it is solvable).

Comment: @Ian Should I parametrize this assigning x and y $\sin a$ and $\cos a$?

Comment: @MarionCrane Michael got a better answer :)

Comment: How about the second part @Ian The farthest point from the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $(x,y,z)=(\cos t,\sin t,-\sin t\cos t)$  Check the derivative is never the zero vector.

Comment: How about the other question? The farthest point from the origin?

Comment: Calculate $x^2+y^2+z^2$ for this parametrization.  When is it greatest?

Comment: Is it $1 $ then?